AG Grid Row Changed
Is there a way to capture when the user moves from one row to another in Ag-grid in angular. Tried row selected which only works when the a row is selected. My Grid is editable (some columns) and if the user moves around the grid using TAB or mouse I need to capture the current row.
Thanks In Advance

selectionChanged?

Tried selectionChanged.. but it does not work..
